# Sending JSON from Android to .NET WCF with international characters. How?

Tags: android, json, internationalization

I'm getting exceptions when I'm trying to POST and my JSON has some international characters.

This is code that I use:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(serviceURL + url);
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Preferences.getAuthorizationTicket(mContext));
            request.addHeader("DeviceSerialNumber", Utility.getDeviceSerialNumber(mContext));
            request.addHeader("OSVersion", "Android v" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestData);
            entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
            request.setEntity(entity);

            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            response.Body = mHttpClient.execute(request, handler);
            response.Code = HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK;
            response.Message = "OK";
```

And this is error I'm getting:

> org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException:
>   Bad Request   at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
>     at
>   com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.processPOST(AsyncProcessor.java:550)
>     at
>   com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.PostMail(AsyncProcessor.java:367)
>     at
>   com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:120)
>     at
>   com.idatt.common.AsyncProcessor.doInBackground(AsyncProcessor.java:28)
>     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

When requestData doesn't have any international (russian, polish, etc) letters than it works fine. What do I miss? Or better yet how do I get traffic from emulator captured in Fiddler or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should specify UTF-8 charset when you create StringEntity:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestData,"utf-8");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)